# Rotativa for PDF getting System.Exception: QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rotativa

I am getting

> System.Exception: QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0

while downloading pdf in portrait mode as below:

```
       var pdf = new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("PdfPartial", new { id = id, pid = pid })
            {
                FileName = "AFE.pdf",
                PageOrientation = Rotativa.Options.Orientation.Portrait,
                PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.A4                   
            };
```

While it's working well with landscape mode as below :

```
var pdf = new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("PdfPartial", new { id = id, pid = pid })
                {
                    FileName = "AFE.pdf",
                    PageOrientation = Rotativa.Options.Orientation.Landscape,
                    PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.A4
                };
```

I have tried by setting properties

```
 PageWidth=670,PageHeight=120
```

It works locally but after publish it doesn't work.I need to download pdf in portrait mode.Is there any fix for above issue?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem in an MVC5/C# app.  I'm using Rotativa 1.6.4.

When Rotativa is installed via Nuget, a directory is created in your project called Rotativa.  In this directory, you will find the wkhtmltopdf.exe executable.

The Rotativa nuget installed provided wkhtmltopdf.exe version 0.12.2.0.

I investigated wkhtmltopdf versions, and discovered that there is an update here:
http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

I downloaded and ran the wkhtmltopdf installer.  It put a new EXE in c:\program files\wkhtmltopdf\bin.  I copied the new EXE from that location into my project directory.  With the latest version of WKHTMLTOPDF.exe in place, the Rotativa functionality worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when returning ViewAsPdf() from one of my controller endpoints. Replacing wkhtml as suggested by Kyle Sullens did not work for me.

This issue seems to be related to part of my Layout page that the wkhtml program couldn't render correctly. I returned a ParialViewAsPdf() to ignore the layout page and this seemed to fix the issue.